# Equivalent of linux's egrep in PHP for a directory of text files?

Tags: php, linux

I want to search a directory of text files in PHP and list all the instances where a string occurs.

In Linux I would use this:

```
egrep Cheese textfile_*.txt
```

*Is there a function in PHP that can peform this without the complexity of first appending everything to an array?*

Comment: [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)?

Comment: Could you apply an example of using glob with a string against a directory of files, not filenames?

Comment: @blarg Errr... wat? That makes no sense.

Comment: PHP does not support the regex flavor you have in your question (however it can search by similar patterns).

Comment: How exactly is this question off topic?

Comment: @blarg Wasn't my solution simple enough? ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The General Case

Let's assume that you want the solution that matches a string of an arbitrary length within an arbitrary number of arbitrarily sized files, and that your system resources are limited. This is most likely scenario, and it's also the trickiest.

You cannot simply load all the files into memory and search them as one large string per file, because this is very memory hungry and actually not particularly efficient in terms of functional complexity (you loop all files, load them into memory, then you loop them again and search the content).

In fact, it would be best to avoid loading entire files into memory at all - what if one of the files is 10GB?

So, first of all, fairly obviously, we need to get a list of the files in the directory. There are a few approaches to this - I see [`glob()`](http://php.net/glob) mentioned a few times - but I would say that the best approach for this algorithm would be to read the entries sequentially and process them one at a time instead of loading the entire list into an array and then iterating it, which in PHP means you either want the [`opendir()`](http://php.net/opendir) family of functions or one of the [`DirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/directoryiterator) family of iterator classes. Many would argue that in modern PHP the latter is the "right" way.

Now you have access to a list of the files in the directory, you need to access the content, and you need to do it without loading the whole file into memory. In PHP that means you're going to want [`fopen()`](http://php.net/fopen) and (since this is a text file) [`fgets()`](http://php.net/fgets). This allows us to process the file one line at a time, so we never load more than one line's worth of data into memory at once. It also has an argument that allows you to specify the maximum line line length, and this should probably be used in case the text file, for whatever reason, contains few/no line breaks.

So we're processing the file in chunks, we can just [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos) each chunk for the search string, right? Well, almost. What happens when the search string crosses the boundary of two (or more) chunks? Here's where it starts to get interesting, and where it starts to become worth looking at more complex string search algorithms (a variant on the [Boyer-Moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) algorithm would probably serve you well here).

Now the only thing you have to determine is how specific you want the match to be - do you want case-sensitivity? Do you want to forgive whitespace differences? Do you want to normalise character sets? These are questions that must be answered and accounted for before you can implement your string search algorithm.

The reality of the situation is that some of these complexities are going to be relatively slow to resolve in PHP - if you were to end up iterating a string a character at a time, for example, something that can be quite fast in C, it would be a real performance killer in PHP.

### Your Case

...may not need this complexity. If you know that you will always be dealing with a small number of fairly small files, simply doing a `strpos(file_get_contents())` combination approach will most likely be fine - although whatever you do, processing one file at a time rather than loading them all into memory before performing any search operations is likely to be desired.

---

In essence, how you implement this depends on a few factors about the environment you are working with - but something like this is possibly very dangerous in terms of resource consumption, and you must consider how your code needs to work now *and in the future* before you can build the correct solution.

Comment: There are some 20 files of 10,000 lines each. My idea was to do the search natively in PHP so I can compare the speed against exec'ing the linux command from PHP.

Comment: @blarg Well I can tell you straight off that you'll never be able to match the speed of a compiled binary executable in PHP, really for anything. If speed is what you are most concerned with then just invoke egrep. But if you keep your code optimised (which probably equates to complex and unmaintainable) you can probably get something workable with that volume of data.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a function in PHP that can peform this without the complexity of first appending everything to an array?

Not one specific function but PHP has:

- RecursiveDirectoryIterator
- RecursiveIteratorIterator
- RecursiveRegexIterator
- GlobIterator
- RegexIterator
- SplFileInfo
- SplFileObject

As these are all iterators, when properly stacked into each other, do allow you to iterate over all matching lines.

For your specific case it's perhaps worth to create a new Iterator which takes arguments similar to egrep in it's constructor and does the stacking / processing inside it's constructor to give this an easy interface.

Or perhaps one for the list of paths/files/SplFileInfo as an iterator and one for the grepping over lines of these to keep it more fluid.

You could also throw in the middle some of the generics in [Iterator-Garden](https://github.com/hakre/Iterator-Garden), like an ExpandingIterator of a DecoratingIterator that turns each SplFileInfo into an SplFileObject.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **[glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)** function:

```
$text_files = glob('directory/*.txt');

foreach($text_files as $text_file) {
   if (strpos('Cheese', file_get_contents($text_file)) !== false) {
      echo 'File ', $text_file, ' contains "Cheese"<br>';
   }
}
```

Comment: Hey this returns false

Comment: Cheese and file_get_contents should be the other way around.